# Where are types for SvelteKit load? Particularly fetch?

Tags: typescript, sveltekit

In SvelteKit, I'm using the `load` function to call an API. I want to use the `fetch` that is passed to the load function - but I'm using TypeScript.

Where's the type for fetch/params/ etc?

```js
    /** @type {import('./$types').PageLoad} */
    export async function load ({fetch}) {
    
      const rndInt = randomIntFromInterval(1, 20)
    
      const res = await fetch(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/${rndInt}`)
      item = await res.json();
    
      return {item}
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is just a matter of applying the type to the load function, it does not matter where its component parts are defined. The only important thing is that `./$types` will be generated by the dev server which has to be running to update correctly.

To apply the type to a function, it is easiest to define it as a `const`:

```js
export const load: PageLoad = ({ fetch }) => {
    // fetch will have the correct type here automatically
}
```

The automatically generated types are in `.svelte-kit/types/src/routes/...`, the hierarchy will mirror the `routes` directory with the actual sources, which allows for the `./$types` import.

The base types are defined in the `@sveltejs/kit` package, see `node_modules/@sveltejs/kit/types/index.d.ts`. If your editor supports a "Go to definition" command, you can just navigate using that. Invoke it on `PageLoad` and/or `Kit.Load` and just have a look around.

Comment: That works, thank you, but causes me issues about async/await usage. Is there a standard method in Sveltekit for doing REST calls in the +page.ts passing it to the +page.svelte?

Comment: For async you just have to add the keyword: `async ({ fetch }) => ...`

Comment: Ah yes, you're right. Apologies - stuck async in wrong place.  https://dev.to/theether0/sveltekit-load-function-behavior-changes-3kb6